# Редирект ссылок с hashcode на ru.stackoverflow

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, хэшкод, миграция

В некоторых вопросах есть ссылки на другие вопросы, и все эти ссылки введут на хэшкод (e.g.: [Как правильно хранить данные в COOKIE?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412584/php-cookie-%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)), если зайти по этой ссылке, то редирект на https://ru.stackoverflow.com/stackoverflow. Может стоит редиректить на аналогичный вопрос на ru.stackoverflow?

*Давайте поможем людям и роботам :-)*

Comment: Мне кажется, технически красивее было бы прогнать по базе замену внутренних ссылок на новые. С другой стороны, в интернете, наверняка есть ссылки на вопросы на ХэшКоде и редирект для них тоже нужен.

Comment: @Nofate да, об этом и речь :). В БД можно все заменить, а на ХэшКоде настроить редирект хотя бы для гуглов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Помогать роботам не обязательно! При импорте мы использовали такие же id вопросов и ответов, как и на ХэшКоде. То есть, `ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/` и `hashcode.com/questions/1/` содержат один и тот же вопрос. Как результат, решением будет добавление перенаправления. Мы настроим его, как только разошлем приглашения на форум всем [подписчикам заявки](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian) и [ХэшКода](http://hashcode.ru).

Comment: А что с помощью людям? Будет просто редирект или вы сделаете replace по БД?

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните про людей. Мы не планируем менять содержимое, добавим редирект с hashcode.ru на ru.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: На ХэшКоде были вопросы, в которых есть ссылки на другие вопросы, размещенные на ХэшКоде (hashcode.ru). Дак вот, ссылки на них так и остались на hashcode.ru. Но вообщем то редирект решает все вопросы, только вдруг вы потом редирект на домене прикроете? :).

Comment: Надеюсь такого не произойдет.

Comment: Вроде бы, редирект уже работает. Может, [meta-tag:status-completed]?